# css/jquery zoom in with animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css, jquery-plugins, css-transitions

I wish to zoom in a div on click. I was trying to zoom in with a smooth animation. Here is my code. Please correct me where I am wrong!

```
$(".contentBox img").click(function(){
    $("#mixedContent").animate({zoom: '150%'}, slow);
});
```

Thanks -

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a zoom property for animate. You would need a to use a plugin or create your own zoom function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should do the trick. (using zoom) -
But I would suggest `$("identifier").on("click", function(){});` (more up to date)

Remember also:

```
zoom: 100%; // at least IE, Chrome 
-moz-transform: scale(1.0);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Put `slow` between quotes:

```
$(".contentBox img").click(function(){
    $("#mixedContent").animate({zoom: '150%'}, "slow");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use something like `height:'+=100',width:'+=100'` instead of `zoom`.